# Redis CLI scan pattern and unlink/delete multiple patterns in a single call

Tags: caching, redis, redis-cli, redis-cache

I have keys stored in my Redis as given below.

- project:page_1_user_1
- project:page_1_user_2
- project:page_1_user_3
- project:page_2_user_1
- project:page_2_user_2
- project:page_3_user_1

To delete the keys matching the pattern, I use the below command as mentioned in many of the answers here on Stackoverflow.

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern '*page_1_*' | xargs -L 100 redis-cli unlink
```

Now, I want to delete multiple patterns in one single query. In the above query, I delete pattern having *page_1* , so I want to delete mulitple patterns like *page_2* and *page_3* all in one single query to the redis-cli. For now I have been looping through my patterns and calling the above redis-cli query. Is it possible to have something like below ?

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern '*page_1_*,*page_2_*,*page_3_*' | xargs -L 100 redis-cli unlink
```

Answer (score 2):

Redis supports [`glob` style patterns](https://redis.io/commands/keys), so you could use

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern '*page_[123]_*'
```

or

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern '*page_[1-3]_*'
```

(You've probably found the answer yourself in the meantime…)